# How i do grouping and transform data in java language

Tags: java, arrays, list, group-by, grouping

I try to use group by in Collectors.groupingBy in java but i can not get data form that i want.
I want to transform this form data :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "A",
        "company_id": "01",
        "company_name": "Company A",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "B",
        "company_id": "01",
        "company_name": "Company A",
    },{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "C",
        "company_id": "02",
        "company_name": "Company B",
    }
]
```

to this data form:

```
[
    {
        "company_id": "01",
        "company_name": "Company A",
        "member":[
          {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "A"
          },
           {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "B"
          }
        ]
    },{
        "company_id": "02",
        "company_name": "Company B",
        "member":[
          {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "C"
          }
        ]
    }
]
```

this form group by company_id.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I would do it: 
First I would create `pojo` objects for both formats, then I would assign each value corresponding ones then I would convert the second object into json as using `gson`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.